# how can i prevent my record from overwrite c++

Tags: c++

how can i prevent my record from overwrite c++

```
cin.get (terminator);
FILE * dat = fopen("Accounts.dat", "wb");

myAccount.username = myUsername;

myAccount.password = myPassword;
int n = 0;


int filenumber=0;
filenumber= n;
fseek(dat,sizeof(myAccount), ios_base :: end);
fwrite(&myAccount, sizeof(myAccount),ios_base ::app, dat);

fclose (dat);
```

Comment: Why are you mixing C's File descriptor with `fstream`?

Comment: filenumber isn't terribly clear to me...

Comment: Care to provide a detailed explanation of what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix `FILE*` with `std::fstream`. Use one or the other.

```
std::fstream File("Accounts.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);

if (File.is_open())
{
    File.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myAccount), sizeof(myAccount));
    File.close();
}
```

or if using C:

```
FILE* file = fopen("meh.dat", "ab+");

if (file)
{
    fwrite(&myAccount, sizeof(myAccount), 1, file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some theory: `fseek` is a C routine found in stdio.h ( `<cstdio>`  in C++). It works with C file descriptors as in the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","w");
  if (pFile!=NULL)
  {
    fseek ( pFile , 0 , SEEK_SET );
    fputs ("fopen example",pFile);
    fclose (pFile);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Notice the `SEEK_SET` flag used with `fseek`.

`ios_base::end` and similar are C++ member constants used in conjunction of the `<fstream>` routines as in the following

```
#include <fstream>      // std::fstream

int main () {

  std::fstream fs;
  fs.open ("test.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

  fs << " more lorem ipsum";

  fs.close();

  return 0;
}
```

You should **NEVER** mix those at any time, it's not typesafe and even if it works there's no guarantee that it would, plus it's not portable and a terrible code practice as well.

There isn't much one could deduce from your small snippet, but if you're encountering weird or erroneous behavior, you should first check these notions out.

References:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/